# onCreate called again when resize in multiview/split screen

Tags: java, android

When I change the screen size in the multiview / split screen mode, the onCreate function in MainActivity is called again.

Because in onCreate I have a ProcessLifecycleOwner observer:

```
ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().GetLifecycle().AddObserver(this);
```

I don't want it to be restarted ... How do I know that onCreate has been called before?

I know you can add:

```
android:configChanges="screenSize"
```

in the manifest, but unfortunately needs to "refresh the layout" when resizing.

Answer (score 0):

Android is going to manage the life cycle, and the programmer needs to deal with all eventualities. On [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle), there's an abbreviated diagram:

[image: android lifecyle]

That would indicate that you would need to manage the observer in the `onStop()`.